# Stanford NER Tool -- training for a new domain

Tags: stanford-nlp

What is the amount of sentences needed to effectively train the CRF for a domain like restauarants (restaurant names, addresses, cusines) or music (artist name, song name genre).

Answer (score 0):

As a point of reference, I believe the CoNLL training data for (location, organization, person, misc) NER has around 14,000 sentences.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot of the kind of data you will be tagging and how variable it will be. I've worked on a project also involving restaurant and music domains. In my case we would be handling user queries, which tend to be short and don't present that much variability (particularly for restaurant, but not for music, which is a very noisy domain). 
For the restaurant domain, training it with ~2k sentences was fine, but of course, if you can get more data, your model will be much more accurate.

For music, the situation is a little bit more tricky since song/band names can be virtually anything. In this case, only data alone might not be enough to get an acceptable accuracy. In my project we used ~5k for music and many features and some additional post-processing to get things right.